# how to get the <ul> id from the javascript variable a which contains the html code and many ul tags and their ids

Tags: javascript

```
var a="<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="Redencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="sRedencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="tRedencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">";
```

how to get the `<ul>` id from the javascript variable a which contains the above code and many ul tags and their ids.

**output should be:**`(Redencontactmenu,sRedencontactmenu,tRedencontactmenu)`

tried the following code but not getting anything:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var elem = elems[i];
        alert(elem.innerHTML);
    }
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Also, **escape your quotes**!

Comment: I don't see any link between the code you've posted and the variable `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var ptn = /<ul[^<]*\sid=(['|"])(.*?)\1/gi;

var ids = [];
while ((match = ptn.exec(str)) !== null) {
    ids.push(match[2]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/DAQwm/3/

Comment: you are not using variable a

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your **HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="Redencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="sRedencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
<input type="text" name="selRedencontact" id="selRedencontact"  />
<ul id="tRedencontactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
```

In your **JavaScript**:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    alert(elem.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the JQuery library, and do it this way :

```
$('ul').each(function(i)
{
   var elem = $(this);
   alert(elem.attr('id')); // alert the Id
   // do whatever you want to the element
});
```

Comment: i want to use javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more easy to use:

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('ul').length;

for(var a=0; a<y; a++){
    alert(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[a].id);
}
```